# Do the various branches of Christianity all claim to be representing the true content of the original foundation and original founder?

Tags: catholicism, bible, protestantism, history

Someone I know made the following claim to me:

> "The various branches of Christianity all claim to be representing the true content of the original foundation and original founder."
> (As opposed to saying that some of them claim [for example] to be rejecting the original foundations and replacing it with something superior).

In order to make this a more focused question, I am only looking for the answer regarding; Catholicism, Protestantism, Anglicanism and Baptist.

Is this true or not?

Please source your answer.

Comment: What foundation? Which founder? I believe this needs more detail to answer.

Comment: If you include LDS in your definition of "Christian" (mainstream Christians do not), the Book of Mormon may qualify as "rejecting the original foundations and replacing it with something superior"...

Comment: I can only see Islam as deliberately rejecting the foundation of Christ and his apostles and  attempting to replace it with what is considered (by them) to be 'superior' to that foundation. That rejection actually goes all the way back to reject Isaac and to choose Ishmael. But surely all who identify as 'Christian' are (professedly) following the foundation which he laid by his own apostles, as Paul makes clear _other foundation can no man lay_ . . . . . The question lacks clarity and detail as to 'foundation', in my view.